# Can I override the UIControlEventTouchUpInside for a UISegmentedControl?

Tags: iphone

I have a UISegmentedControl which I'd like to use to perform a certain action if you click the already selected item.

My thinking is basically something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UISegmentedControl * testButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", nil]];
    [self.view addSubview:testButton];
    [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void) clicked: (id) sender{
    NSLog(@"click");
}
```

(And in `clicked:` I'd just do some check to see if the new selected index is different from the old selected index before the click)

The problem is I can't seem to override the action for the TouchUpInside control event.  Any help appreciated!

-S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a subclass to get the behavior you want.  Make a subclass of UISegmentedControl that has one BOOL ivar:

```
BOOL _actionSent;
```

Then, in the implementation, override the following two methods:

```
- (void)sendAction:(SEL)action to:(id)target forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendAction:action to:target forEvent:event];
    _actionSent = TRUE;
}

- (void) setSelectedSegmentIndex:(NSInteger)toValue {
    _actionSent = FALSE;

    [super setSelectedSegmentIndex:toValue];

    if (!_actionSent) {
        [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        _actionSent = TRUE;
    }
}
```

There are probably other ways but this worked ok for me.  I'd be interested to learn of other approaches.

Answer (score -1):

Use UIControlEventValueChanged with UISegmentedControls.

Comment: The problem with that is if the value has changed then obviously the user hasn't touched the item that's already selected.

Comment: Agree that this doesn't answer your question but it did help me so I gave it an up vote.